# How would you check if deny insecure transport IAM policy works?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-iam

I'm trying to test if my policy that denies insecure transport works. However, every action I do seems to be secure. How would one go about testing this?

```
{
  "Id": "ExamplePolicy",
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Action": "dynamodb:*",
      "Effect": "Deny",
      "Resource": [
        "*"
      ],
      "Condition": {
        "Bool": {
          "aws:SecureTransport": "false"
        }
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: Have you tried using aws cli  `--endpoint-url` to use `http` endpoint?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Marcins comment ought to work but you could also try testing the reverse of that policy to verify it does what you think it's doing

Try changing temporarily to the following, and make sure your normal dynamodb calls are denied for using SecureTransport

```
"Condition": {
  "Bool": {
    "aws:SecureTransport": "true"
  }
}
```

Just be sure to switch it back!